# I've know idea where to look, maybe it's an infinite loop? (C++, using VS2012)

Tags: c++, numbers, infinite-loop

Well, I'll introduce myself first. I'm Ben, a 17-years old 'game-programmer' from the Netherlands who just has begun to program in C++ (started about a month ago, but programming for a year right now) (and I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 as compiler). Now, I am 'learning it myself' but I still do use a book and that book is called 'Beginning C++ Through Game Programming, Third Edition' by Michael Dawson.

I just did finish with chapter two and the last excersize was: "Write a new version of the Guess My Number program in which the player and the computer switch roles. That is, the player picks a number and the computer must guess what it is."

Here follows the code of the 'Guess My Number' Program:

```
// Guess My Number
// The classic number guessing game

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));  //seed random number generator

    int secretNumber = rand() % 100 + 1;    // random number between 1 and 100
    int tries = 0;
    int guess;

    cout << "\tWelcome to Guess My Number\n\n";
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a guess: ";
        cin >> guess;
        ++tries;

        if (guess > secretNumber)
        {
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";
        }
        else if (guess < secretNumber)
        {
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nThat's it! You got it in " << tries << " guesses!\n";
        }
    } while (guess != secretNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I was busy with thinking, programming testing and it just wouldn't work.
It seems I got stuck with such a infinite loop. But I can't find the problem.

Here's the code, and other ways to fix this are welcome, just keep in mind that I don't know a lot of the language. ;)

```
// Guess My Number 2
// The classic number guessing game with a twist

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    int secretNumberComputer = rand() % 100 + 1;
    int secretNumberPlayer;
    int triesPlayer = 0;
    int triesComputer = 0;
    int guessPlayer;
    int guessComputer;
    int tooHighPlayer;
    int tooLowPlayer;
    int correctPlayer;
    int tooHighComputer;
    int tooLowComputer;
    int correctComputer;
    int selectNumberIncorrect;
    int lowerGuessComputer = 101;
    int higherGuessComputer = 0;


    cout << "Welcome to Guess My Number\n\n";   

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a guess: ";
        cin >> guessPlayer;
        ++triesPlayer;

        tooHighPlayer = (guessPlayer > secretNumberComputer);
        tooLowPlayer = (guessPlayer < secretNumberComputer);
        correctPlayer = (guessPlayer == secretNumberComputer);

        if (tooHighPlayer)
        {
            cout << "Too high!\n\n";
        }
        else if (tooLowPlayer)
        {
            cout << "Too low!\n\n";
        }
        else if (correctPlayer)
        {
            cout << "\nThat's it! You got it in " << triesPlayer << " guesses!\n\n";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error, check code!\n\n";
            break;
        }
    } while (!correctPlayer);


    cout << "Now it's time for you to pick a number and then the computer will guess.\nEnter a number between 1 and 100: ";


    do
    {
        cin >> secretNumberPlayer;
        selectNumberIncorrect = (secretNumberPlayer > 100 || secretNumberPlayer < 1);
        if (selectNumberIncorrect)
        {
            cout << "\nHey, that isn't a number between 1 and 100! Please pick a number that is: ";
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    } while (selectNumberIncorrect);

    guessComputer = (rand() < lowerGuessComputer && rand() > higherGuessComputer);
    cout << "\n\nNow the computer is going to try to guess your number:" << endl;
    cout << "Computer, take a guess: " << guessComputer << endl;
    ++triesComputer;

    tooHighComputer = (guessComputer > secretNumberPlayer);
    tooLowComputer = (guessComputer < secretNumberPlayer);
    correctComputer = (guessComputer == secretNumberPlayer);
    lowerGuessComputer = (rand() % 100 + 1 && rand() < guessComputer);
    higherGuessComputer = (rand() % 100 + 1 && rand() > guessComputer);

    if (tooHighComputer)
    {
        cout << "Too High!\n\n";
        guessComputer = lowerGuessComputer;
    }
    else if (tooLowComputer)
    {
        cout << "Too Low!\n\n";
        guessComputer = higherGuessComputer;
    }
    else if (correctComputer)
    {
        cout << "\nThat's it! You got it in " << triesComputer << " guesses!\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error, check code!\n\n";
    }


    do
    {
        cout << "Computer, take a guess: " << guessComputer << endl;
        ++triesComputer;


        if (tooHighComputer)
        {
            cout << "Too High!\n\n";
            guessComputer = lowerGuessComputer;
        }
        else if (tooLowComputer)
        {
            cout << "Too Low!\n\n";
            guessComputer = higherGuessComputer;
        }
        else if (correctComputer)
        {
            cout << "\nThat's it! You got it in " << triesComputer << " guesses!\n\n";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error, check code!\n\n";
            break;
        }
    } while (!correctComputer);


    if (triesComputer < triesPlayer)
    {
        cout << "You lost against the computer!\n\n";
    }
    else if (triesComputer > triesPlayer)
    {
        cout << "You won!\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It's a tie!\n\n";
    }

    cout << "Thank you for playing! Goodbye!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to dump a huge bit of code and just ask, "What's wrong?" I recommend reading the FAQ. :)

Comment: Look at breakpoints. I find them useful in situations like these.

Comment: If I was a guessing computer, I would use a binary search.

Comment: It's not like I didn't looked and searched, I did, for hoirs and hours and I just could not find it. And I  just wanted to provide you the full information, since it uses a lot of information I gave at the beginning of the program. I just want to know what I'm doing wrong, not why this question is formulated wrong. ;)

Comment: Where is the infinite loop? What output do you see? What do you input at the prompts to reproduce the problem?

Comment: And as I said before,  I'm not so skilled at all, and I don't know how to use functions yet.

Comment: A perfect binary search (on a range of 100) has a worst case of 7 guesses, and an average case of 5.6 guesses.  Random guessing in the range (for which your math is 100% wrong) should have an average case of about 7.3.

Comment: Output is first guessing the number of the computer,  then putting in a number to guess for the computer,  and thats where it all goes wrong, first give a random number and then  repeating to give that same random number... until i shut it down (that program)

Comment: @Ben your problem is obvious from the description alone. I also provided the answer you need. But your program's logic is flawed in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

In this block you aren't checking the computer's guess for correctness (assigning correctComputer), so the loop continues forever, unless it guessed correctly the first time.

```
do
{
    cout << "Computer, take a guess: " << guessComputer << endl;
    ++triesComputer;


    if (tooHighComputer)
    {
        cout << "Too High!\n\n";
        guessComputer = lowerGuessComputer;
    }
    else if (tooLowComputer)
    {
        cout << "Too Low!\n\n";
        guessComputer = higherGuessComputer;
    }
    else if (correctComputer)
    {
        cout << "\nThat's it! You got it in " << triesComputer << " guesses!\n\n";
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error, check code!\n\n";
        break;
    }
} while (!correctComputer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second `do` loop never recalculates the computer's guess.

i.e. you have the computer guess one number *before* the `do` loop, then in the loop you keep checking if that *one* guess is too high or too low, never recalculating its value. It'll obviously never end.

You need to do the computer's guess calculation inside the second loop.

EDIT

Also, this logic is incorrect:

```
lowerGuessComputer = (rand() % 100 + 1 && rand() < guessComputer);
higherGuessComputer = (rand() % 100 + 1 && rand() > guessComputer);
```

The guess will always be 0 or 1 because the result of the right-hand-side operation is a boolean. In fact, I don't know what you're trying to do there. You're performing `&&` between an integer and a boolean. I also don't understand why you are calculating two different guesses - you should calculate one number within the range of the higher/lower parameters you were given.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Kevin Tran wrote, please check the valid input type for cin.

Imagine someone typing characters instead of integers.

so

```
cin >> guessPlayer;
```

can be written as

```
if (cin >> guessPlayer) {
        // Do you logic here
    }
else {
 cout<<"Enter numbers only. :)";endl;
 continue;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of analyzing the code you posted which has numerous flaws, let's just think about what your program has to do: The user will pick a random number, and the computer will try to guess that number.

So, your program flow should go like this:

The computer picks a random number. It prints it out and asks the user to choose if the number is too high, too low or correct. (i.e. by asking the user to type '1' if too high, '2' if too low or '3' if it's right).

If the user types '3' then obviously you're done.

If it's too high, the computer picks a new random number (smaller than it's last guess) and tries the above logic again.

If it's too low, the computer picks a new random number (greater than it's last guess) and tries the above logic again.

Now let's try and implement some code that implements the above:

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int range_low = 0;    // The number the user picked is greater than this
    int range_high = 100; // The number the user picked is smaller than this

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));

    do
    {
        // We want to generate a random number between range_low and range_high. We do this
        // by generating a random number between zero and the difference of "low" and "high"
        // adding it to low and adding one more.           
        int guess = range_low + ((rand() % (range_high - range_low)) + 1);

        cout << "I'm guessing your number is " << guess << "... how did I do?" << endl
             << "    [1: too high, 2: too low, 3: you got it!] ";

        // Now let's see how we did...

        int choice;

        cin >> choice;

        if(choice == 3)
        {
            cout << "Be amazed at my psychic powers! For I am a computer!" << endl;
            break;
        }

        if(choice == 2)
        { 
            cout << "Hmm, ok. I was sure I had it. Let's try again!" << endl;
            range_low = guess;
        }

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Really? Ok, ok, one more try!" << endl;
            range_high = guess;
        }
    } while(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Here are two exercises for you to improve the above:

First, try to compare the logic of this code against the logic of your code and see where your code differs - try to understand why it was wrong. It will help to try to execute the program using pen and paper, just like you were a computer that understood C++.

Second, try to add code to ensure that the computer never guesses the same number twice.